# simulate click in a SVG file when load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want create a focus on location "Molise, italy" when load a  SVG map in my page http://goo.gl/0ZywjM

so i have created this simple script in jquery

```
<script>
jQuery('#path20684').click();
</script>
```

it work , but only after load the page and after insert this from chrome console , if insert this on footer not work because the svg file it not part of dom.  how i can solve this, or have other solution  ?

**update** it work only with this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    jQuery('#path20684').click();
}, 1000);
```

but with this every second is clicked , so i think the problem is the script start before a SVG file is loaded, how solve ?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CYhgZ/90/

please check the above link for demo

```
 $(function() {
// when click event happens below code executed        

$('path').on('click', function() {
         alert("clicked")
     });

//simulating click event automatically when page load
         $('path').trigger("click");
         //or
         //$('path').click();
     });
```

Comment: not understand your code, i request a simulate click when load page, your code require a click, true ?

Comment: so where is your solution in your answer  ?, i have already tried  jQuery('#path20684').click(); but not work

Comment: this is the code i understand from your answer , <script>
 jQuery(function() {
// when click event happens below code executed        

jQuery('#path20684').on('click', function() {
   jQuery('#path20684').click();
     });

//simulating click event automatically when page load
         jQuery('#path20684').trigger("click");
         //or
         //$('path').click();
     });
</script> it correct ? not work

Comment: only$(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('#path20684').trigger("click");});  is fine not required all the code.

Comment: enter this code in developer tools console.log(jQuery('#path20684')); if html returns the above code should work else some other problem

Comment: already tried this "$(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('#path20684').trigger("click");});" work on chrome console , not work in script before </body> when load page

Comment: i tried "$(window).on("load",function(){});" not work, but you have see the link of site http://goo.gl/0ZywjM ?

Comment: loading map with ajax call. try to write click event in ajaxstop method.$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {

});

Comment: umm a ajax call require big change on plugin, i think in mapplic.js i can include this click

Comment: if you access to mapplic.js triiger click event in ajax complete or  write in  .done(function(){...});